# existence of $W \subset X^*$ which separates the points in separable normed space $X$.

Tags: normed-spaces, separable-spaces

Let $X$ be a separable normed space. I have to see that there exists a numerable subset $W \subset X^*$ such that $W$ separates the points in $X$. I could start the proof but I have a problem: what does "separates the points in $X$" mean? Thanks

Comment: Hint: use Hahn-Banach

Comment: but how? which function I need to take in $X^*$ to apply Hahn-Banach?

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1952021/a-dual-of-separable-banach-space-contains-a-countable-total-set).

Comment: my space is separable but is not Banach

Comment: That doesn't matter, the dual of $X$ and the dual of the completion of $X$ can be canonically identified.

Comment: What does "separates the points in $X$" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A, B$ be sets, and $\mathscr{F}$ a family of functions from $A$ to $B$. Then $\mathscr{F}$ *separates points* in $A$, if for all $a_1, a_2 \in A$ with $a_1 \neq a_2$ there is an $f \in \mathscr{F}$ such that
$$f(a_1) \neq f(a_2)\,.$$
Thus a point of $A$ is determined by the indexed family of its images under elements of $\mathscr{F}$, in other words the map $\Phi \colon A \to B^{\mathscr{F}}$ given by
$$\Phi(a) = \langle f(a)\rangle_{f \in \mathscr{F}}$$
is injective.

If $A$ and $B$ are vector spaces over the field $k$, and $\mathscr{F} \subset \mathscr{L}(A,B)$ is a family of $k$-linear maps, then $\mathscr{F}$ separates points if and only if for every $a \in A \setminus \{0\}$ there is an $f \in \mathscr{F}$ such that $f(a) \neq 0$.

Vector spaces and linear maps are more than we need for this characterisation by the way, it holds (with a slight modification of notation, replace "$0$" with the identity elements "$e$") for arbitrary groups and a family of group homomorphisms.

The proof that this characterises families separating points is easy. On the one hand, $a \in A \setminus \{e\}$ (I'm using the group setting, $e = 0$ for vector spaces) means $a \neq e$, so if $\mathscr{F}$ separates points there is an $f \in \mathscr{F}$ such that $f(a) \neq f(e) = e$. On the other hand, if $a_1 neq a_2$, then $a_1^{-1}a_2 \neq e$, so by assumption there is $f \in \mathscr{F}$ with
$$e \neq f(a_1^{-1}a_2) = f(a_1)^{-1}f(a_2)\,,$$
which is equivalent to $f(a_1) \neq f(a_2)$, and thus $\mathscr{F}$ separates points.

For your specific problem, pick a countable dense subset $D = \{x_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ of $X$ (it may be convenient to assume $0 \notin D$) and for every $n$ choose an $f_n \in X^{\ast}$ (it can be convenient to choose them such that $\lVert f_n\rVert = 1$ for all $n$) based on $x_n$ alone (hint: Hahn-Banach). If you made the right choices, $W = \{ f_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ will separate points in $X$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. According to your context, such sequence $\{f_n\}$ can be easily found. And $f_n(x_n) \neq 0$, so it is good. How ever, if we take an arbitrary $x \in X$, there exists a subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ in $D$ such that converges to $x$. What $f \in W$ can I take to show that $f(x) \neq 0$? probably something like $\lim_{k \to \infty} f_{n_k}$ in some sense, or $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} f_{n_k}$. I am stuck here

Comment: You can take $f_n$ if $x_n$ is sufficiently close to $x$. What "sufficiently close" means depends on how you chose the $f_n$. (Of course you need to choose $f_n$ appropriately, just requiring $f_n(x_n) \neq 0$ isn't enough. You need $\lvert f_n(x_n)\rvert$ large enough.)

Comment: I have spaned each $x_n$, so Hahn-Banach has given me $f_n \in X^*$ given by $f_n(\alpha x_n) = |\alpha| \|x_n\|$. It is a way to obtain also $\|f_n\| = 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Doesn't it seem enough to you?

Comment: There's a modulus too much, should be $f_n(\alpha x_n) = \alpha \lVert x_n\rVert$. I suppose that's just a typo caused by temporary inattention. That choice is really good. Now, with $$f_n(x) = f_n(x_n) - f_n(x_n - x) = \lVert x_n\rVert - f_n(x_n - x)\,,$$ what would be "sufficiently close" to guarantee $f_n(x) \neq 0$?

Comment: what "sufficiently close" means with that $f_n$? and why do we have that $f_n(x) \neq 0$ in that case?

Comment: What bound for $\lVert x_n - x\rVert$ guarantees $f_n(x) \neq 0$?

Comment: I don't get what you meant

Comment: Can you find a $\delta > 0$ (it may depend on $x$ and/or $x_n$) such that $\lVert x_n - x\rVert < \delta$ implies $f(x) \neq 0$?

Comment: I cannot find the expression for $\|x_n - x\|$ where we expand $f_n(x) = \|x_n\| - f_n(x_n - x)$, so I think not

Comment: Can you relate $f_n(x_n - x)$ and $\lVert x_n - x\rVert$?

Comment: the relation is given because of the continuity of $f_n$, right?

Comment: And $\lVert f_n\rVert$ gives an explicit relation.

Comment: which relation? I know that given $\varepsilon > 0$, if $\|x_n - x\| < \delta$, then $||f_n(x_n - x)| < \varepsilon$. If I take $\varepsilon = \frac{\|x_n\|}{2}$, I think it is sufficient to obtain $f_n(x) > 0$. How can I use $\|f_n\|$? Pd: the bound for $\|x_n - x\|$ is given because of the density of $D$

Comment: Since $\lVert f_n\rVert = 1$, we have $\lvert f_n(x_n - x)\rvert \leqslant \lVert x_n - x\rVert$. Thus it suffices to have $\lVert x_n - x\rVert < \lVert x_n\rVert$. But we don't know $\lVert x_n\rVert$, so we need a bound on the distance in terms of $x$ only. Can you find a $\delta(x)$ such that $\lVert y - x\rVert < \delta(x)$ implies $\lVert y - x\rVert < \lVert y\rVert$? [Then pick $n$ such that $\lVert x_n - x\rVert < \delta(x)$ and you're done.]

Comment: what do I need to keep in mind to show that $|f_n(x_n - x)| \leq \|x_n - x\|$? Is my argument to show $f_n(x) \neq 0$ incorrect?

Comment: Just the general $\lVert T(y)\rVert \leqslant \lVert T\rVert\cdot \lVert y\rVert$ for continuous linear maps between normed spaces, and the fact that we have chosen the $f_n$ to have norm $1$. Thus $$\lvert f_n(x_n - x)\rvert \leqslant \lVert f_n\rVert \cdot \lVert x_n - x\rVert = \lVert x_n - x\rVert\,.$$

Comment: I understand now why $|f_n(x_n - x)| \leq \|x_n - x\|$, but I do not understand why you want to search $\delta(x)$ such that $\|y - x\| < \delta(x)$ implies $|y - x| < \|y\|$. Also I do not know how to find it. But I know that we can find $\delta > 0$ such that $\|x_n - x\| < \delta$ implies $|f_n(x_n - x)| < \frac{\|x_n\|}{2}$ as I said, I think it would be sufficient

Comment: Indeed that would be sufficient. But how do you know that we can find such a $\delta > 0$?

Comment: because of the density of $D$. As $x \in \overline{D} = X$, there exists $\{x_{n_k}\} \subset D$ such that converges to $x$, then for all $\delta > 0$ there exists $k_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\|x_{n_k} - x\| < \delta$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k \geq k_0$. Then given $\delta > 0$, we can choose $m = n_{k_0}$, and we have $\|x_m - x\| < \delta$.

Comment: So far so good. But how do you get from $\lVert x_m - x\rVert < \delta$ to $\lvert f_m(x_m - x)\rvert < \frac{\lVert x_m\rVert}{2}$? That doesn't work for all $\delta > 0$, only for sufficiently small ones. And we must find a specific $\delta$ for which it works. (Or prove that it works for all sufficiently small $\delta > 0$.)

Comment: Continuity from $f_m$: given $\varepsilon = \frac{\|x_m\|}{2}$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that if $\|x_m - x\| < \delta$ then $|f_m(x_m - x)| < \frac{\|x_m\|}{2}$. It is true that it does not work for all $\delta > 0$, but the density of $D$ gives us a $m$ sufficiently big such that the $\delta$ given by the continuity works to obtain $|f_m(x_m - x)| < \frac{\|x_m\|}{2}$, doesn't it?

Comment: The problem with that is that you don't know $x_m$ yet when you choose $\delta$, so you don't know what $\varepsilon = \frac{\lVert x_m\rVert}{2}$ will be. You are given $x$, and from knowing $x$ alone you must be able to produce a $\delta > 0$ such that $\lVert x_n - x\rVert < \delta$ guarantees $f_n(x) \neq 0$. From above, we have that it suffices to have $\delta < \lVert x_n\rVert$. But again the problem is that we only find $x_n$ *after* $\delta$. So, given $x$, can we find $\delta > 0$ such that $\lVert x_n - x\rVert$ implies $\delta < \lVert x_n\rVert$?

Comment: do we need to find $\delta(x)$ such that $\|x_n - x\| < \delta(x)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: No, and we can't. Since $\{x_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is dense in $X$, there are $x_n$ arbitrarily far away from $x$. We need just one $x_n$ that is sufficiently close. But we must define/specify "sufficiently close" first. Say $\lVert y - x\rVert < \frac{1}{2}\lVert x\rVert$. What can you say about $y$?

Comment: From $\|y - x\| < \frac{\|x\|}{2}$ I don't know what can I say from $y$, it seems in fact close to $\|x\|$, what do you mean with what I can say about $y$?

Comment: Can you say anything about $\lVert y\rVert$ for example?

Comment: I think
$$
|\|y\| - \|x\|| \leq \|y - x\| < \frac{\|x\|}{2},
$$
then
$$
- \frac{\|x\|}{2} < \|y\| - \|x\| < \frac{\|x\|}{2},
$$
so $\|y\| \in \left(\frac{\|x\|}{2} , \frac{3 \|x\|}{2}\right)$ should be true.

Comment: Yup. Now, can you find $\delta > 0$ (depending on $x$) such that $\lVert x_n - x\rVert < \delta$ implies $\delta < \lVert x_n\rVert$, and therefore $f_n(x) \neq 0$?

Comment: Take $x_n = y$ and $\delta = \frac{\|x\|}{2}$. If $\|x_n - x\| < \delta$ then $\delta < \|x_n\|$, so
$$
f_n(x) = \|x_n\| - f_n(x_n - x) \geq \|x_n\| - \|x_n - x\| > \|x_n\| - \delta > 0.
$$
Is it correct? (I am supposing $f_n(x_n - x) \geq 0$, we can I guess)

Comment: If we have a complex vector space, it doesn't quite work so. Then we can either look at $\operatorname{Re} f_n(x)$ (and the computation shows that is $> 0$), or take the modulus, and get $$\lvert f_n(x)\rvert \geqslant \lVert x_n\rVert - \lvert f_n(x_n-x)\rvert > 0\,.$$

Comment: Ok but I am going to suppose that my field is $\mathbb{R}$, but thank you for the suggestion. All in all to check if I have understood well. I take $\{x_{n_k}\}$ from the density of $D$ such that converges to $x$. For the definition of that convergence I keep in mind $\delta = \frac{\|x\|}{2}$. So I can define $m = n_{k_0}$, and we see also that $f_m(x) \neq 0$. Is it ok?

Comment: It's okay, but more complicated than needed. You don't need a sequence converging to $x$. You start with $\delta$ (that can be $\frac{1}{2}\lVert x\rVert$ or smaller, but the argument won't work with larger $\delta$). Then since $D$ is dense you know that there is some $x_n$ with $\lVert x_n - x\rVert < \delta$. Since $\delta \leqslant \frac{1}{2}\lVert x\rVert$ it follows that $\lVert x_n\rVert > \delta$, and hence $$f(x) = f(x_n) - f(x_n - x) \geqslant \lVert x_n\rVert - \lVert x_n - x\rVert > \lVert x_n\rVert - \delta\,.$$

Comment: As $D$ is numerable, I defined $D = \{x_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, so that's why I took $\{x_{n_k}\}$, then my argument is equivalent to yours, right?

Comment: Yes, but the point is that there's no need to pick a sequence, and doing that distracts (a little) from the important parts of the argument. The $\delta$, and the one $x_n$ we use to show $f_n(x) \neq 0$.

Comment: I see, with my sequence I can take $m = n_{k_0}$ but you say directly that there exists $n$ such that satisfies the propierties of this $m$. But from this step, both ways seem the same

Comment: Thank you so much for the support